# data binding in wpf combo box in data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox

I am having one problem related to `ComboBox` of `DataGrid`. Data is binding but it is not showing in the `ComboBox` after binding. My code is like below:

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="UsgSrc">
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Name="cbUsgSrc"  
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UsgSrcUOMS}}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UsgSrc}" 
                      SelectedValuePath="UtType" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="UtType">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code for static resource:

```
UsgSrcUOMS.ObjectDataProvider UsageSrcUOMS = null;
UsageSrcUOMS = (ObjectDataProvider)FindResource("UsgSrcUOMS");
UsageSrcUOMS.ObjectInstance = objUtView;
Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell = obj.GetCell(dgMtrHdr, J, 11);

if (cell != null)
{
    ContentPresenter panel = cell.Content as ContentPresenter; 
    if (panel != null)
    {
       ComboBox cmbUsUtilit = obj.GetVisualChild<ComboBox>(panel);
       cmbUsUtilit.IsEnabled = true;
       if(objUtView!=null) 
         cmbUsUtilit.ItemsSource = objUtView;cmbUsUtilit.SelectedIndex=2;
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this. Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the Binding to the StaticResource, something like that

```
<ComboBox Name="cbUsgSrc"  
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource UsgSrcUOMS}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=UsgSrc}" 
          SelectedValuePath="UtType" 
          DisplayMemberPath="UtType">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi Sine,just now I tried like what you said.But I am receiving following error in the code behind. 'System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider' is not a valid value for property 'ItemsSource'.

Comment: can you please share the code where you define the StaticResource UsgSrcUOMS

Comment: Hi Sine,Thanks for giving reply.In the code behind I am assigning data to UsgSrcUOMS.ObjectDataProvider UsageSrcUOMS = null;UsageSrcUOMS = (ObjectDataProvider)FindResource("UsgSrcUOMS");
UsageSrcUOMS.ObjectInstance = objUtView;Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell = obj.GetCell(dgMtrHdr, J, 11);
if (cell != null){ContentPresenter panel = cell.Content as ContentPresenter;
if (panel != null){ComboBox cmbUsUtilit = obj.GetVisualChild<ComboBox>(panel);
cmbUsUtilit.IsEnabled = true;if(objUtView!=null) cmbUsUtilit.ItemsSource = objUtView;cmbUsUtilit.SelectedIndex=2;}}

Comment: can you please update your question with the xaml-code for the objectdataprovider!